# Determine all values of scalars p,q and r for which the given linear system is consistent:

Tags: linear-algebra

The original linear system is:

> x + 2y - 3z = p
>
> 2x + 3y + 3z = q
>
> 5x + 9y - 6z = r

Partway into reduction, I reach the system:

> x + 2y -3z = p
>
> -y + 9z = q - 2p
>
> -y + 9z = r - 5p

I am very new to linear algebra and am unsure how to proceed from here; this step seems significant for the fact that rows 2 and 3 are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. The question is "find all values of $p,q,r$ for which the system is consistent.

You managed to prove that "as long as $p=\frac{1}{3}(r-q)$, the system is consistent. And if $p\neq\frac{1}{3}(r-q)$, the system is NOT consistent."

So, your answer would be "the system is consistent for all values of $p,q,r$ for which $p=\frac{1}{3}(r-q)$.

and that's your answer :)

Here's something interesting to notice: you're thinking "$r$ and $q$ could be anything, but then $p$ is bound to be $\frac{1}{3}(r-q)$.

You could just as well think "$p$ and $r$ could be anything, but then $q$ is bound to satisfy $p=\frac{1}{3}(r-q)$, that is, $q$ must be $r-3p$." Or, you could think of $p$ and $q$ as free, which then constrain $r$.

Or, you could think "all three variables are together bound by the equation $q-r+3p=0$", so instead of $p,q,r$ having full three-dimensional freedom, they are bound to a plane with equation $q-r+3p=0$ in $(p,q,r)$-space.